# SQL Query: Largest number of guns

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

Schema is below:

Ships(name, yearLaunched, country, numGuns, gunSize, displacement)

Battles(ship, battleName, result)

where name and ship are equal. By this I mean if 'Missouri' was one of the tuple
results for name, 'Missouri' would also appear as a tuple result for ship.

(i.e. name = 'Missouri' ,  ship = 'Missouri)
They are the same

Now the question I have is what SQL statement would I make in order to list 
the battleship amongst a list of battleships that has the largest amount
of guns (i.e. gunSize)

I tried:

```
SELECT name, max(gunSize)
FROM Ships
```

But this gave me the wrong result.

I then tried:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM Ships s,
   (SELECT MAX(gunSize) as "Largest # of Guns"
   FROM Ships
   GROUP BY name) maxGuns
WHERE s.name = maxGuns.name
```

But then SQLite Admin gave me an error saying that no such column 'maxGuns' exists
even though I assigned it as an alias: maxGuns

Do any of you know what the correct query for this problem would be?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you mentioning the `Battles` table? It does not appear to be related with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your query is that the subquery has no column named `name`.

Anyway, to find the largest amount of guns, just use `SELECT MAX(gunSize) FROM Ships`.
To get all ships with that number of guns, you need nothing more than a simple comparison with that value:

```
SELECT name
FROM Ships
WHERE gunSize = (SELECT MAX(gunSize)
                 FROM Ships)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist because you are trying to alias a subquery in the 'Where' clause, instead of aliasing specific column from a table. In order to identify the ship with the most guns you could try something like:

```
    with cte as (select *
   ,ROW_NUMBER()  over (order by s.gunsize desc) seq
    from ships s )

    select * from cte 
    where seq = '1'
```

Another approach could be: And it will only select the 1st row,containing the ship with highest number of guns.

```
     select Top 1 *
     from ships s 
     order by s.gunsize desc
```

Comment: This does not work with SQLite. And the question asked for *all* ships with the most guns.

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH TAB_SHIPS(NAME, NUMGUNS,DISPLACEMENT) AS (SELECT NAME, NUMGUNS,DISPLACEMENT FROM SHIPS AS S
LEFT JOIN CLASSES AS C
ON S.CLASS=C.CLASS
WHERE C.NUMGUNS >=ALL(SELECT NUMGUNS FROM CLASSES C1 WHERE C1.DISPLACEMENT = C.DISPLACEMENT ) 
UNION
SELECT SHIP, NUMGUNS,DISPLACEMENT FROM OUTCOMES AS O
LEFT JOIN CLASSES AS C
ON C.CLASS=O.SHIP
WHERE C.NUMGUNS >=ALL(SELECT NUMGUNS FROM CLASSES C1 WHERE C1.DISPLACEMENT = C.DISPLACEMENT ) )

SELECT NAME FROM TAB_SHIPS
WHERE NUMGUNS IS NOT NULL
```